# Copy a row to the same table by changing few column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to copy a row from a table into the same table by changing few column values. Depending on the shape in that row I have to copy the row from shape table into the same table with new id.

**I tried this:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_CopyAnnotation

@AnnotationID int,
@AssetVersionID int,
@NewAssetVersionID int

AS
DECLARE @NewAnnotationID int
DECLARE @Shape varchar(50)
BEGIN
insert into AnnotationMain(Text,x, y,Shape,Color,z1,JobID,AssetID,UserID,UserName,Department,AssetVersionID,HideAnnotation)
select  Text
        ,x
        ,y
        ,Shape
        ,Color
        ,z1
        ,JobID
        ,AssetID
        ,AssetVersionID
        ,UserID,UserName
        ,Department
        ,@NewAssetVersionID
        ,1
        from AnnotationMain where AnnotationID=@AnnotationID;
        --set @NewAnnotationID=@@IDENTITY

select @NewAnnotationID=AnnotationID,@Shape=Shape from Proofing.AnnotationMain where AnnotationID=@@IDENTITY  

update AnnotationMain 
set Annoation_num=(select (max(Annoation_num)+1) 
                   from AnnotationMain
                   where AssetVersionID=@AssetVersionID)
where AnnotationID=@NewAnnotationID

IF(@shape='ellipse')
BEGIN 

Insert into CircleTable(AnnotationID,x1,x2,y1,y2)
select @NewAnnotationID
       ,x1
       ,x2
       ,y1
       ,y2
from CircleTable where AnnotationID=@AnnotationID
select result=1;
END

ELSE IF(@shape='rectangle')
BEGIN

Insert into RectangleTable(AnnoationID,x,y,w,h)
select @NewAnnotationID
       ,x
       ,y
       ,w
       ,h
from RectangleTable where AnnoationID=@AnnotationID
select result=1;
END

ELSE IF(@shape='pencil')
BEGIN

Insert into PencilTable(AnnoationID,x1,y1,cord)
select @NewAnnotationID
       ,x1
       ,y1
       ,cord
from PencilTable where AnnoationID=@AnnotationID
select result=1;
END
END
GO
```

**But it gives me an error**

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Sp_CopyAnnotation, Line 23
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

And I'm not bale to make out where I'm going wrong

Comment: The error message says it all. Your `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements does not have the same number of columns .

Comment: 14?? @FelixPamittan  Only 13 are there in SELECT also

Comment: Yup, sorry. Miscounted. But the idea still stays the same.

Comment: As a side note: please refrain from prefixing your stored procedures with `sp_`. Read [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) for more info.

Comment: Ohh ya.. Thanks.. Since it was in same line I didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AssetVersionID` missing in Insert column list

```
INSERT INTO AnnotationMain
            (Text,
             x,
             y,
             Shape,
             Color,
             z1,
             JobID,
             AssetID,
             AssetVersionID, --Missing 
             UserID,
             UserName,
             Department,
             AssetVersionID,
             HideAnnotation)
SELECT Text,
       x,
       y,
       Shape,
       Color,
       z1,
       JobID,
       AssetID,
       AssetVersionID,
       UserID,
       UserName,
       Department,
       @NewAssetVersionID,
       1
FROM   AnnotationMain
WHERE  AnnotationID = @AnnotationID;
```